# How do I rewrite this bash command line into zsh?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, zsh

I need to input this command. It is written in `bash`, but my terminal is `zsh`. How do I rewrite it?

```
ssh username@rserver.com -L 127.0.0.1:8888:*:11111
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are just arguments to `ssh`, they are not `bash` specific. You probably want to escape your glob, though (although that's true in `bash` as well).

```
ssh username@rserver.com -L 127.0.0.1:8888:\*:11111
```